# The parallax here is not working, how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, parallax, web-frontend

I'm trying to do create a parallax effect on this webpage: http://therealrohanm.me/Falcon-Hacks-Website/

View the code here: https://github.com/Meeshbhoombah/Falcon-Hacks-Website/tree/gh-pages

I'm having a few issues, the first being the orange mountains (as pictured here: https://github.com/Meeshbhoombah/Falcon-Hacks-Website/blob/gh-pages/images/parallax-1.png) are not displaying. They are supposed to be directly behind the pink trees.

My second issue is that the trees are too "zoomed in." I want them to be able to see the entire line of trees/mountains.

The reason I combined these questions into one is that I feel like they're both related, but I'm unsure how to accomplish them. I've tried many different ways. How do I do these things?

Comment: Having your project in a gitHub makes it difficult for others to help you. If you could upload your images to some hosting site and then post a jsFiddle with the relevant code you'll have a much higher chance of getting help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an absolute position problem...

anyway setting `left:initial ; right:200px` will get it on screen;

[image]